# where to put the word simultaneously

Tags: adverb-position

I am aware that adverbs are relatively "Free" in terms of their place in sentences.

For the adverb "simultaneously", I could use it in a sentence either like

"I am doing A and B simultaneously" or

"I am simultaneously doing A and B".

I was wondering if it was possible for the word "simultaneously" to be placed between A and B.

If I were to, would I write out the sentence like

"I am doing A simultaneously to B"?

Or is this sentence simply ungrammatical? If so, is there another way to make a sentence so that "simultaneously" goes between A and B?

Comment: You need the adjective *simultaneous* — meaning *at the same time* — here. *I am doing A simultaneous with B.*

Comment: "simultaneously" should be used as it is modifying the verb "doing" in that case. I doubt the adjective simultaneous can be used in that sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not common,

*simultaneously with / to* + gerund-participial

is perfectly good English when used as an adjunct in clause structure.

Some examples:

***Simultaneously with protecting these interests***, which are genuine, we should say that we want to advance our ideals.

*There are frequent complications brought on by the use of untrained or undertrained anesthetist personnel, or by the physician opting to manage the anesthesia **simultaneously with performing surgery***

*Doing all this **simultaneously with keeping high quality manpower** is a substantial goal for any military.*

***Simultaneously to starting a business***, Louis started courting.

So I'd say the following is also perfectly good English:

*I am [gerund participial] simultaneously to / with [gerund participial]*

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just a quick question. Is "simultaneously to" more frequently used than "simultaneously with"? Or as you mentioned above, is it not possible to know which expression is more frequently used because they are not commonly used?

Comment: _With_ is more frequent than _to_ , or, at the very least, more common in the materials available to me.